# Is it good to create multiple indices on a single Elastic Search server?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I intend to use one index specifically for live search terms and the other for some other content. I would like to know if this will take a performance hit over time. To get a little specific I am expecting 5 million + records in each index.

Comment: It depends on many factors related to the available hardware on your machine (specifically RAM, CPU and diskspace), the size of your documents, the number of shards per index, etc. On a conventional box (32GB RAM, 4 core CPU), 2 indices with 5Mio small documents is not a problem I would say, but again, there are too many hidden variables, so if you can shed some light on all that, that would help.

Comment: I have 8GB RAM with 8 cores. I am beginning to think now that you suggest 32GB as "conventional". Apart from that I could say the size of the documents indexed will be about 200 to 300 bytes each. Honestly, my concerns are more IO related.  If concurrent read writes on parallel indices may be a problem or not.

Comment: When it comes to ES, nothing is carved in stone and every use case is different. I'd say, bring up your bigdesk or marvel plugin, go ahead and index your documents and monitor your cluster while it ingests your data. When done, if all went well, go ahead and do some load testing while monitoring your cluster. It's the only way to know whether you need to tune your settings/hardware/mappings/queries, etc... I wouldn't be too worried, your documents would take about 1-2GB in space depending on how they are analyzed, so that's probably ok.